# Using Priors in Decision trees

Tags: machine-learning, cart, unbalanced-classes

I have been building a predictive model using Decision Trees. The data is highly skewed (only 2% of the target variable is "Yes" and others are "No") and I have to increase the precision for "Yes". I am using Rattle , a tool built on R (which in turn uses rpart library) for decision trees. I am using a prior of (0.9,0.1). Let's suppose I am getting rules in following fashion

Rule number: 1 [Target=Yes cover=306 (4%) prob=0.42]
 Feature condition I
 Feature condition II
 .............................

I know that prior will mean assuming 10% of the population is "Yes" which actually is 2% and therefore summing up the weighted probabilities is coming to  (4%*0.42 + 3%*0.22 + ....) = 0.1

How are actual "Yes" distributed across the segments? So in the test data set instances which fit Rule 1 will have 0.42/5 = 8.4% of Yes (because total is 10% and 2% is the actual) ?

Answer (score 0):

So I printed the scores, and I cross-checked with the underlying data and indeed when we divide the count of actuals comes out to be that !! I hope anyone who is searching for the same issue may be helped, though it is a too specific one. :)